# Export access query to existing excel workbook then open workbook

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a query that exports to a workbook and it works just fine but I would like to open the workbook after the query is exported. I tried adding "true" to the end of the code but that produced an error.

Here is the code

```
Private Sub CmdPrintX_Click()
DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryInternalPOs", acViewNormal, acEdit
 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
    "qryInternalPOs", "T:\PURCHASE ORDERS\POs created in access\qryInternalPOs.xlsx", 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried "I would like to open the workbook after the query is exported" insearchbox above? ;(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
    Private Sub CmdPrintX_Click()
    Dim XlsApp As New excel.Application
    Dim XlsWB As New excel.workbook
    Dim filePath As String
        filePath = "T:\PURCHASE ORDERS\POs created in access\qryInternalPOs.xlsx"
        DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryInternalPOs", acViewNormal, acEdit
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
           "qryInternalPOs", filePath, 1
        Set XlsApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Set XlsWB = XlsApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    End Sub
```

Comment: I would recommend `Application.FollowHyperlink filePath` as shorter and aware of filetype (e.g pdf)

Comment: Yes, this would be the alternative. I use the other one because I usually would like to manipulate the Excel file by code.